# Is there any vector image tool designed around creating isometric images?

Tags: windows, vector-graphics

I want to create some vector graphics for a scene that is done entirely isometrically. I am wondering if there are any image creation tools for Windows that are specially designed for making this job easier, e.g. having an option to snap-to-grid that helps create the angles?

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means a comprehensive answer. I've recently learned of [Cuttle](http://cuttle.xyz), a vector editor that is web based, eliminating platform restrictions.

I'm only now learning of the features, but it does have snap-to capability, allowing one to snap to other portions of the drawing (snap to geometry) and to the grid (snap to grid). The grid resolution is dependent upon your zoom level, but snap to grid works to 0.001 mm resolution (just tested) and larger.

If that doesn't work for you, there is [SolveSpace](https://solvespace.com/ref.pl), a free multi-platform parametric 3D editor, which works just fine in 2D:

> Snap Grid Spacing
>
> This specifies the pitch of the snap grid, in inches or millimeters.
> By default, the grid is not displayed; it may be shown by choosing
> View → Show Snap Grid. Points are never automatically snapped to the
> grid. To snap a point, select that point, and then choose Edit → Snap
> to Grid. Comments (Constrain → Comment, cosmetic text) may be snapped
> to grid in the same way.

There are other programs, including Inkscape (free, multi-platform) that may not be quite as easy to use.